# Javascript .append() with .fadein()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a function that adds text to an element called #textBox. I want the text to fade in the box so, here is my code.

```
var addText_3 = function(text) {
    $("#textBox").append("<p><i>" + text + "</i></p>").hide().fadeIn(500);
};
```

So, my function appends to text and hides it so it can fade in. However, I just want the appended element to fade in. When I try this function, all of the other text in the element also fade. Is there a way to only make the element I am appending to fade in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("<p><i>" + text + "</i></p>").appendTo("#textbox").hide().fadeIn(500);
```

Create the new element, append it to `#textbox`, and fade it in.

```js
var text = 'Stack Overflow';
$("<p><i>" + text + "</i></p>").appendTo("#textbox").hide().fadeIn(500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textbox">Some text</div>
```

Comment: You need to hide it before you can fade it in, yeah? `style="display: none"`

Comment: @Mathletics Fixed. Demo added.

Answer (score 1):

The chaining of function does not return what you expect : it returns `#textBox` while you thought it'll returns your freshly created text node.

So, you have to call both the `hide()` and `fadeIn()` functions on your text node instead. 
`appendTo()` is the function you'd rather use as it returns the caller (call it on your new node).

Example (with jQuery's clean node creation) :

```
var addText_3 = function(text) {
     var text_node = $("<p>").append($("<i>", {html: text})).hide(); //Can use text instead of html
     text_node.appendTo("#textBox").fadeIn(500);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This one's my personal pref

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/56a48023ddf2350afa193c1809558bf5)

```
  var text = 'asdfasdfasdf';
  $("<p><i>" + text + "</i></p>").fadeIn(500).appendTo($('#textBox'));
```